# Reinvoke function on model update in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, service

First off, I apologize in advance if my terminology or approach is off - I come from a structural engineering background and am trying to learn javascript and AngularJS through a small pet project.

My question is: How do I re-invoke a function `updateMe()` within a service whenever the model updates. A sample code and plunker are below.

Initially, this code will run fine and the result will be calculated. If `a` or `b` are updated, their updated values are propagated to all controllers, but the value of `result` is not updated.

I've tried playing around with `$scope.$watch()` but I couldn't get it to work, nor am I sure that is the right approach.

In my actual project, the function in question depends on several properties of the myservice object, and generates JSON data which is then plotted with [n3-charts](https://github.com/n3-charts/line-chart). I want to make the plot interactive by regenerating the data when the user updates a property of the myservice object.

```
angular
   .module('app', []);

//some function to be evaluated when the data in myservice changes
function updateMe(x, y) {
  return x * y;
}

//Define a service (to provide data to multiple ctrls)
function MyService() {
   var myservice = this;
   myservice.a = 2;
   myservice.b = 5;
   // I am trying to get 'result' to update when any of the input parameters update
   myservice.result= updateMe(myservice.a, myservice.b); 
}
angular
  .module('app')
  .service('myservice', MyService);

// Controller that uses myservice data in the view
function FirstCtrl(myservice) {
   var vm = this;
   vm.myservice = myservice;

}
angular
   .module('app')
   .controller('FirstCtrl', FirstCtrl);

// Another Controller that uses myservice data in the view      
function SecondCtrl(myservice) {
   var vm = this;
   vm.myservice = myservice;
}
angular
   .module('app')
   .controller('SecondCtrl', SecondCtrl);
```

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zj9DyHuZwvTScHbosk7M?p=preview) similar to the code above.

Comment: Show us what you tried with `$watch`, it is a correct approach.

Comment: I was trying to use something like:     `$scope.$watch(vm.myservice, function(newVal,oldVal) {
        vm.myservice.result = updateMe(vm.myservice.a, vm.myservice.b);
   });` in one of the controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you  can use an ng-change function to recalculate the values

```
<input type="number" step="1" ng-model="first.myservice.a" ng-change="first.myservice.updateAll(first.myservice.a)">


  myservice.updateAll=function()
 {
   myservice.result = updateMe(myservice.a, myservice.b);
 }
```

Whenever there is a change on your model the `updateAll` triggers and you can do all your recalculations inside that.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jD5a7OPDLbkYbRxcriL6?p=preview) is the working example.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This solution works in my app, and I now have a live view of my data! Although I'm sure there's a way to get $scope.$watch to work, this seems to be the cleanest way to go.